# CI and automation

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration

I'm about to start CI, and I have a fully automated verification system, but as I read, the automation run will start after the developer code is pushed to the cloud (and that happens many times a day). When I run the whole automation bundles it takes around 1 hour to finish the tests.
So I'm wondering if the time is acceptable, if not, what can I do to decrease the time, is there some kind of certain method that could help. Tools, please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to say jenkins execution time is longer than local? Addionally, you can try parallel execution.

Comment: Actually, I tried jenkins and since it headless, it was faster.
But my question is; when I do a local run it takes one hour, does this will achieve the purpose of CI(detect bugs early).
And unfortunately parallel execution doesn't work with our site (business wise).

Comment: Well that completely depends on your project management team as in what should be the frequency of your builds. Unless you have problem where your code is taking too much time when it should not, this place is not a good place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: First having a build time of one hour? this is not continious integration cause the feedback takes too long...so usual time frames are max. 5-6 minutes...The question is what takes the time? Running unit/integration tests? What kind of machine are you using? And why does parallel execution for the maven build not work? If so you have a bigger issue in your build...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, it takes time cause it test every feature on the site. I'm using windows with a good specs PC. And my issue with parallel execution isn't with code, it's with the site business, since there's no multi-session login for each user, and there's a lot of test cases rely on each other.

Comment: So the tests take so much time...So the question is can you find a way to use less time consuming integration tests to get the same result? Or buying a faster machine? Or using multiple machines ?

Comment: "So the question is can you find a way to use less time consuming integration tests to get the same result?" That's why I posted the question, since i'm out of options :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe to think about to run automated tests at the end of a day. I also had similar situation, and came to solution to use cron jobs, that are set at midnight.

Maybe to think about that, and to avoid testing for each build.

If automated testing is needed for each build, try to introduce nodes (for eg. for Jenkins) You could add additional nodes and run on several machines, I think I also did for BitRise similar thing.

Divide tests cases with some logic, eg. logins in one run, negative testcases in different and so on.

Chop down testcases to certain smaller sections, use only core tests for each build, and complete run at the end of day.

There is lot of measures how to ensure faster running and not of them is programatically handled.

But also programatically can be drastically increase speed of tests, parallelisation, concurrent runs, grid etc.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Kovacic,
Thanks for your reply, I have already scheduled run starts at the end of the day.
And I was thinking to avoid testing for each build, but in this case I won't achieve CI.
I'll wait to see if anybody has other ideas, if not I'll strip down the suites to smaller units.

Comment: Hope I helped. tnx